# Using a function from python flask with a button in html

Tags: python, html, flask, button

I've now googled for 2 days for different flask/python guides + stack overflow regarding this and I found none that fit my situation. I'm trying to build a simple form, which gets data by user input, so my flask python app can read the info and use that info to put that data up to an SQL DB. That part works fine and I can display all the data below the form just how I would like it, but the problem is I've also made a function inside the python file that deletes all data from that table, and I could get that working but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do it without making a POST request inside the Html that doesn't require any input fields to be filled and also how to differentiate that button from the other button. Also, I have a button at the end of each row that should delete that specific row but I haven't gotten that "far" yet.

Okay so now after my problems I can tell you what I've already tried. I've tried setting the function to an onclick of the button in the Html, nothing happens, I've tried different request.form['submit_button'] == 'Delete All'-detectors and in python, I've also tried to check for DELETE-events inside Html, but jinja always throws a different error, nothing happens, the page changes when it shouldn't or requires the filling of the form, which it shouldn't.

Heres my Html:

```
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <style>
         table, th, td {
         border: 1px solid black;
         }
      </style>
      <title>Index</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      {% block content %}
      <h1>Projektin Lisäys</h1>
      <form method="POST" action="">
         <legend>Uusi Projekti</legend>
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td>Projektin nimi</td>
               <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Projektin status</td>
               <td>
                  <select name="status">
                     <option>On Track</option>
                     <option>Off Track</option>
                     <option>At Risk</option>
                  </select>
               </td>
            <tr>
               <td>Luontipäivä</td>
               <td><input type="date" name="luonti" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Viimeisin aktiviteetti</td>
               <td><input type="date" name="viimeisin" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Tilavaatimus</td>
               <td><input type="number" name="tilavaatimus" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Privaatti vai public</td>
               <td>
                  <select name="public">
                     <option>Privaatti</option>
                     <option>Public</option>
                  </select>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
         <input name="form" type="submit" value="Add"/>
      </form>
      <table style="margin-top: 5%">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th style="width: 8%;">Name</th>
               <th style="width: 7%;">Status</th>
               <th style="width: 3%;">Public</th>
               <th style="width: 15%;">Created on</th>
               <th style="width: 20%;">Latest activity</th>
               <th style="width: 5%;">Disk storage</th>
               <th style="width: 25%; text-align: left; margin-left: 5%;">Delete</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         {% for projekti in session['data'] %}
         <tr>
            <td>{{ projekti[1] }}</td>
            <td>{{ projekti[2] }}</td>
            <td>{{ projekti[3] }}</td>
            <td>{{ projekti[4] }}</td>
            <td>{{ projekti[5] }}</td>
            <td>{{ projekti[6] }}</td>
            <td><input name="form" type="submit" value="Delete"/></td>
         </tr>
         {% endfor %}
      </table>
      <input type ="submit" name="Delete All" onclick="del_all()"/>
      {% endblock content %}
   </body>
</html>
```

And here is the code for the python side:

```
from forms import ProjektinLisays
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session
from datetime import datetime
import mysql.connector
import forms

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "hello"
db = mysql.connector.connect()

cursor = db.cursor()
def projektientulostus():
    kaikkidata = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM projektit")
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    session['data'] = data

def projektinlisäys(nimi, status, public, lvuosi, lkk, lpv, vvuosi, vkk, vpv, tila):
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO projektit(nimi, status, public, created_on, latest_activity, required_disk_storage) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (nimi, status, public, datetime(lvuosi, lkk, lpv), datetime(vvuosi, vkk, vpv), tila))
    projektientulostus() # Päivitys uuden rivin lisäyksen jälkeen
    db.commit()

def definitions():
    nimi = request.form['name']
    status = request.form['status']
    public = request.form['public']
    if public == "Privaatti":
        public = 0
    else:
        public = 1
    luonti = request.form['luonti']
    luonti= luonti.split("-")
    lvuosi = int(luonti[0])
    lkk = int(luonti[1])
    lpv = int(luonti[2])
    viimeisin = request.form['viimeisin']
    viimeisin = viimeisin.split("-")
    vvuosi = int(viimeisin[0])
    vkk = int(viimeisin[1])
    vpv = int(viimeisin[2])
    tila = request.form['tilavaatimus']
    lista = [nimi, status, public, lvuosi, lkk, lpv, vvuosi, vkk, vpv, tila]
    return lista

def del_all():
    cursor.execute("DELETE FROM projektit")

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    cursor = db.cursor()
    projektientulostus() # Kaikki projektit näkyviin sivulle
    forms = ProjektinLisays()
    if request.method == 'DELETE':
        if request.form['submit_button'] == 'Delete All':
            print("DA")
        elif request.form['submit_button'] == 'Do Something Else':
            print("DSE")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        lista = definitions()
        projektinlisäys(lista[0], lista[1], lista[2], lista[3], lista[4], lista[5], lista[6], lista[7], lista[8], lista[9])
        cursor.close()

    return render_template('index.html', forms=forms)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Sorry if there's too much code, but it's really hard for me to figure out what's necessary at this point and what is not.
PS. I also know that the layout/UI is terrible, but thats not important at this point, I would just want the functionality for the 2 buttons. 1 for deleting one row at a time depending on where I press, and one for deleting all of them through the function.

Comment: A: This is  a dumb way of doing this I'm sure, B: This always happens to me that when I go and ask someone/someplace for help with any problem, I figure some solution out myself. But anyways here's the code I had to add to my python.

`@app.route("/delall", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def delall():
    del_all()
    return redirect(url_for("home"))`

Answer (score 1):

A: This is  a dumb way of doing this I'm sure, B: This always happens to me that when I go and ask someone/someplace for help with any problem, I figure some solution out myself. But anyways here's the code I had to add to my python:

```
@app.route("/delall", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def delall():
    del_all()
    return redirect(url_for("home"))
```

and in my HTML I have this:

```
<input type ="submit" name="Delete All" value="Delete All" onclick="{{ url_for('delall') }}"/>
```

Not really sure which parts of either of them are necessary but this did at least the Delete all button problem. Not sure how I can manage the deleting one at a time though.